# I am try to seed using factory classes but get BadMethodCallException : Call to undefined method Database\Factories\ProductFactory::unique()

Tags: php, laravel-8, factory, seeding

Here are the codes:

This is the code in ProductFactory.php file where i defined the data to be generated for the Product

```
    <?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {

        $product_name = $this->faker->unique()->words($nb=4, $asText=true);
        $slug = Str::slug($product_name);

        return [
            'name' => $product_name,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'short_description' => $this->faker->text(200),
            'description' => $this->faker->text(500),
            'regular_price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(10,500),
            'SKU' => 'DIGI'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(100, 500),
            'stock_status' => 'instock',
            'quantity' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 200),
            'image'=> 'digit_'.$this->unique()->numberBetween(1,22).'.jpg',
            'category_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,5)
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the code in CategoryFactory.php file where i defined the data to be generated for the Category.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Category::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $category_name = $this->faker->unique()->words($nb=2, $asText=true);
        $slug = Str::slug($category_name);

        return [

            'name' => $category_name,
            'slug' => $slug
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the DatabaseSeeder.php where i called the two Models

```
    <?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use \App\Models;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        
        \App\Models\Category::factory(6)->create();
        \App\Models\Product::factory(22)->create();
    }
}
```

I ran the command **php artisan db:seed** but i got above stated error I am stake now because everything seems fine

Answer (score 1):

All your other unique calls use `$this->faker->unique()...` except this one:

```
'image'=> 'digit_'.$this->unique()->numberBetween(1,22).'.jpg',
```

Change it to use `faker` too:

```
'image'=> 'digit_'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,22).'.jpg',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
$category_name = $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,20);
```